# Content script stops listen to background script after some time

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When browser action is clicked I am passing data from background to content script. In the begining, it works fine, but after one cup of coffee, it stops working. The background script is sending a message, but the content script, isn't responding.  The content script is running inside all open tabs.

Actually, I solved this issue by manually inecting content script every time tab is open. Over and over again. It works but creates multiple instances of content.js, I guess that that's not good for performance

Also, tried to use long live port connection instead. But didn't find a way to send messages from background to content script on browser action event

```
// manifest.json

    "content_scripts": [
    {
         "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
         "js": ["js/content.js"]
       }
     ],

      "background": {
        "scripts": ["js/background.js" ],
        "persistent": false
      },

// background.js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(sendfunc); // waiting for the browser action


function sendfunc(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.windows.getAll({ populate:true},function(windows){
            allTabs = windows
            sendMessage(tabs)
        });
    }
}

function sendMessage(tabs){
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { 
    message: 'test'
  })
}

// content.js, stops receiving messages after some time, runs on multiple tabs
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log ('Got message', request)
});
```

I expect that the content script will continue to receive messages from background script, but it doesn't happen.

Comment: This fragment of code isn't sufficient to diagnose the problem. Seeing your manifest.json may help. A surefire solution is debugging in devtools (both for the background script and the content script).

Comment: Added relevant path of manifest. During debugging found out, that background script is receiving browser action, then when script was just loaded everything works, but if I browse other tabs for some time and get back, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You're using a persistent:false background script which unloads after 5 seconds of its own inactivity, which may explain the problem in case it's caused by some other code in your background script that relies on a global variable being defined (like `allTabs`).

Comment: Omg, I can't believe! Seems like it solved my problem. So many hours wasted on this, thank you very much!

Comment: @wOxxOm you are a hero.. this anwer is hard to find with google but i think that this piece of code comes from copying the google tutorial... and it's hard to notice.. wish i could give you +10 here ( did give you on another answer though )